# Calling the empty sub-dictionary from the nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to call out the sub-dictionaries of a nested dictionary to do some operation

For example, given a nested dictionary

```
A = {0: {2: {}}, 1: {0: {}, 2: {}}}
```

Let say I want to create a sub-dictionary `k: {}` to all empty dictionaries, what command should I use?

My thought:

```
for item in A:
  if A[item] == {}:
    A[item] = k
```

However, it seems that the code cannot get into the deepest layer. The output is still the same as input. I guess that's because the first layer is not empty, and my code can only "scan" the first layer.

***Updated:***

I am doing some operations about finding the shortest path, the operation itself is rather clumsy. To lower the perplexity of my question, I will use operation_A to indicate the operation here.

At the very first step, there is an empty dictionary `A = {}`, after the operation, it will return some results (a, b in this case), and I will create a sub-dictionaries inside, for instance, A will become `{a: {}, b: {}}`, and the next step, the operation_A will run through a and b separately, and have different result append to that dictionaries.

Take an example
`operation_A return c,d from a`
`and return e from b`

The dictionary A will then become `{a: {c: {}, d: {}}, b: {e: {}}}`

However, I have encountered the issue that I fail to get to the deep layer of the nested dictionary.

Comment: If it's always nested at the same depth, you could add an extra level to your loop.

Comment: But this approach will create aliases: if you then add a key/value pair to `k`, it will appear in all those formerly empty dictionaries. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sounds like a job for recursion.

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: I have updated my original question, see if that clarifies my question... @joanis

Comment: (Seems that I can only @ one person at the same time, haha...) I have updated my original question, see if that clarifies my question... @Pierre D

Comment: It does! But I am struggling from that... I am just a student from a python elementary course... @Johnny Mopp

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @FletcherNg I've expanded my answer to cover what I think you might be trying to do, but your question is still not 100% clear. Can you review my edited answer and let me know if you need more?

Comment: For every empty dictionary inside the nested dictionary, I will run through the operation and create a new sub-dictionary using the result obtained from the operation. I am not a native speaker, please do excuse my clumsiness of my expression, sorry. @PierreD

Comment: Really appreciate your help here, I will try to digest your solution first, I am still not clear if I am on the right track. @joanis

Comment: How about calling out the deepest layer of each sub-dictionary? If i use for item in dictionary, it will only call out the first layer , but what if I want the deepest one instead? @joanis

Comment: @FletcherNg My recursive solution does that, no? In any case, the short answer is that if you have a nested structure, you need to dive into it, either with fixed loops, for fixed depths, or with recursion, for variable depths.

Comment: It does solved part of the question I am facing, that's probably because I was expressing my question wrongly in the very first place... However, I still need to call out the deepest layer to do operation_A, but I don't know how to write a recursion from that... @joanis

Answer (score 1):

##### The basic fix to your code, nest one more level

If you always have the same fixed depth, you can add an extra level of looping to your code:

```
for item in A:
  for subitem in A[item]:
    if A[item][subitem] == {}:
      A[item][subitem] = k
```

If you wanted something more general, though, please clarify your question.

##### Slightly more elegant code: use `.items()`

I don't really like looping with indices that much, I prefer using `.items()`.

This code is equivalent:

```
for k1, v1 in A.items():
  for k2, v2 in v1.items():
    if v2 == {}:
      v1[k2] = k
```

The only use of an index I have to keep is `v1[k2]` in the assignment, because assigning to `v2` instead would only change the reference in the middle of the loop, not the structure it's in.

##### Generalizing the code with recursion

Next, let's consider a more general recursive solution, where the values to replace might not all be at the same depth:

```
def replace_empty_dicts(my_dict, replacement):
  for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if v == {}:
      my_dict[k] = replacement
    elif isinstance(v, dict):
      replace_empty_dicts(v, replacement)

replace_empty_dicts(A, k)
```

##### Final thoughts: this is probably not what you want!

A final comment: all of these solutions will create aliasing. After replacing all these empty dicts with `k`, any change you make to any of them will be made to all of them, since they all point to the same dict. I think my code can show you how to iterate through your structure, but you'll have to solve what you really want to do instead of assigning `k` everywhere.